# Show Different Facebook Tab App on Page for Different Locales

Tags: facebook, tabs

Does anyone know whether it's possible to show different Facebook Tab Apps in the left-hand menu of a Page depending on the locale of the user visiting the Page?

For example, I have 3 similar, but subtly different, apps built in three different languages, but only want any one user to see the app in the left-hand menu which correlates to their locale - does anyone know if is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No but you could make it just one application and use Facebook Translations for you app for the tab name.  Then you could look at the signed request that Facebook POST's to your site and then show the best content based on the users country or language.  You would need to map different language options to the versions you have.

Answer (score 0):

In the answer of the signed request is not only, if user is fan or admin, you can find his language,too. So you can use do..case with it